# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "self" (Rails 4 Active Record transaction, postgresql 9.4))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

When creating a model Deal, I use an after_create to create prizes on the DealPrize table.

Deal and DealPrize have a belong to/has_many relations: a Deal has many Deal prizes and a Dealprize belongs to a Deal.

It works like this: inside Deal, I have a column 'prize-number' and I use an after_create so that evetytime the amdin creates a new deal, the app takes this prize_number column, and create this volume of prizes (inserting as many rows as necessary) inside the DealPrize table.

**I fail to use my Rails app moel variable inside a postgresql query.**

Here is a working query (**using figures instead of variables**). It perfetcly writes it on my database.

**model deals.rb**

```
CONNEXION = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

    def create_prizes
      Deal.transaction do        
        self.120000.times do |i|
          CONNEXION.execute "INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at) 
          values ( 62, '2009-01-23 20:21:13', '2009-01-23 20:21:13')"
        end
      end
    end
```

But when I replace the example values by variables as it should be, I get an error.

```
CONNEXION = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

    def create_prizes
      Deal.transaction do        
        self.120000.times do |i|
          CONNEXION.execute "INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at)
          values ( self.id, '2009-01-23 20:21:13', '2009-01-23 20:21:13')"
        end
      end
    end
```

If I use self.if, I get error

```
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "self"
```

I tried also self.id, id, deal.id, deal_id, self_id, nothing works.

thanks for your help,

**EDIT - ADDED for dimakura**

Before optimizing with raw sql and transactions:

```
def create_prizes
      self.1200000.times do
        prizes = DealPrize.create(:deal_id => self.id, :admin_user_id => self.admin_user_id)
        prizes.save
      end
    end
```

**LATEST CODE with the help of dimakura**

```
CONNEXION = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

def create_prizes
  Deal.transaction do  
    self.1200000.times do |i| 
      st = CONNEXION.raw_connection.prepare("INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at) values (?, ?, ?)")
      st.execute(self.id, Time.now, Time.now)
      st.close
    end
  end
end
```

Getting error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I've shown you a correct way. Now you have changed your question. You should ask another question if you like.

Comment: put it inside question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406552/wrong-number-of-arguments-1-for-2-3-for-postgressql-query-rails-4-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
CONNEXION.execute "INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at)
values ( #{self.id}, '2009-01-23 20:21:13', '2009-01-23 20:21:13')"
```

But it's not a recommended approach. You should never interpolate parameters like this.

The better approach is:

```
st = CONNEXION.raw_connection.prepare("INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at) values (?, ?, ?)")
st.execute(self.id, Time.now, Time.now)
st.close
```

Comment: for your 'even better' solution, I get "undefined method `prepare' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter:0x00000008cb4618>"

Comment: Yes, it should be `CONNEXION.raw_connection.prepare("INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at) values (?, ?, ?)")`. I've updated answer as well.

Comment: Don't you have a `DealPrize` model too?

Comment: Why not to execute simply: `DealPrize.create(deal_id:62)`?

Comment: I have a working query but as I need a mass insert (>100K rows), I want to improve it by using raw sql+transaction. I'm puttting now my original pure rails active record query using DealPrize

Comment: Why not to execute simply: DealPrize.create(deal_id:62)? => I need also created_at and updated_at as they'can't be null

Comment: created_at and updated_at are populated automatically by Rails

Comment: yes usually, but here transfering data on a after_create method seems not to do it. if i remove created_at and updated_at form the query, here is what I get:  "ERROR: null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (170, not_yet_clicked, null, null, 157, null, null, null, null)."

Comment: tx for your help, i've pout my latest code with your feedback: self.id now is working but I get an error => see my EDIT

Comment: I think by the way, I should put outside the query like a constant : TIME= Time.zone.now like this it won't be calculated at each 120,000 times. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I use postgresql, not mysql , if it's important

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it with string interpolation i.e. `#{self.id}` instead of `self.id`:

```
   def create_prizes
      Deal.transaction do        
        self.120000.times do |i|
          CONNEXION.execute "INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at)
          values ( #{self.id}, '2009-01-23 20:21:13', '2009-01-23 20:21:13')"
        end
      end
    end
```