# wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3) for Active Record postgresql query (Rails 4/postgresql 9.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

When creating a model Deal, I use an after_create to create prizes on the DealPrize table.

Deal and DealPrize have a belong to/has_many relations: a Deal has many Deal prizes and a Dealprize belongs to a Deal.

It works like this: inside Deal, I have a column 'prize-number' and I use an after_create so that evetytime the amdin creates a new deal, the app takes this prize_number column, and create this volume of prizes (inserting as many rows as necessary) inside the DealPrize table.

model deals.rb

```
CONNEXION = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

def create_prizes
  Deal.transaction do  
    self.1200000.times do |i| 
      st = CONNEXION.raw_connection.prepare("INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at) values (?, ?, ?)")
      st.execute(self.id, Time.now, Time.now)
      st.close
    end
  end
end
```

Getting error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)
```

Source- I arrived to this thanks to Dimakura on question [ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "self" (Rails 4 Active Record transaction, postgresql 9.4))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405986/error-missing-from-clause-entry-for-table-self-rails-4-active-record-transac)

**EDIT: complete error log**

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3):
  app/models/deal.rb:391:in `block (2 levels) in create_prizes'
  app/models/deal.rb:390:in `block in create_prizes'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
  app/models/deal.rb:389:in `create_prizes'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:225:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_create_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:501:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:219:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:120:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
   () home/mmathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bundler/gems/activeadmin-5eb26b02bf63/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:159:in `block in save_resource'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:77:in `try!'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:63:in `try'
   () home/mmathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bundler/gems/activeadmin-5eb26b02bf63/lib/active_admin/callbacks.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in define_active_admin_callbacks'
   () home/mmathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bundler/gems/activeadmin-5eb26b02bf63/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:158:in `save_resource'
   () home/mmathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bundler/gems/activeadmin-5eb26b02bf63/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:148:in `block in create_resource'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:77:in `try!'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:63:in `try'
   () home/mmathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bundler/gems/activeadmin-5eb26b02bf63/lib/active_admin/callbacks.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in define_active_admin_callbacks'
   () home/mmathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bundler/gems/activeadmin-5eb26b02bf63/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:147:in `create_resource'
  inherited_resources (1.6.0) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:33:in `create'
  app/admin/deal.rb:67:in `create'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  request_store (1.2.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/mmathieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/mmathieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/mmathieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What's is giving you that error? Which method call?

Comment: @muistooshort Not sure to be able to decipher this from my logs: I am adding it to the question=> see EDIT

Comment: See the best answer in this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805627/prepared-statement-on-postgresql-in-rails it seems that for postgres you need to give a name to your `prepare` (not assign it to a variable) and then run `exec_prepared`

Comment: definitely seems like this. thanks so much

Comment: Got many errors : created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444971/undefined-method-exec-prepared-and-error-prepared-statement-xxx-already-ex