# undefined method 'exec_prepared' on Rails 4 postgresql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Every time, I submit a form supposed to create a Deal and sending a very high nb of Prizes (>200K) to the Prize table using a transaction and raw postgresql, I have first the error 'undefined method exec_prepared' then if I reload the form then I get a new error 'ERROR: prepared statement 'xixie' already exists'.

I used this question [wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3) for Active Record postgresql query (Rails 4/postgresql 9.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406552/wrong-number-of-arguments-1-for-2-3-for-active-record-postgresql-query-rails) and [Prepared Statement on Postgresql in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805627/prepared-statement-on-postgresql-in-rails) to create the following Postgresql query:

**models deals.rb**

```
CONNEXION = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection

def create_prizes
      Deal.transaction do  
        self.prize_number.times do |i| 
         st = CONNEXION.prepare('xixie', 'INSERT INTO prizes (deal_id) values ($1)')

          values = [ { value: self.id} ]
          st.exec_prepared('xixie', values )
          st.close()
        end
      end
    end
```

I have this problem in Local (not production) and I am not using any puma/unicorn. I do use Zeus and Guard.

Is it impossible with Rails4/postgresql prepared_statements to insert multiple rows at a time ?

How can I change the query to make it work ?

Also as Rails gives me ' ERROR: prepared statement 'xixie' already exists', I had to change multiple times the name of the prepared_statements but will they "live" forever? how can I "kill" them after I do all theses iterations trying to find the appropriate query.

**EDIT**

Updated the code after some proposed answer:

```
CONNECTION = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection

def create_prizes
      Deal.transaction do  
        self.prize_number.times do |i| 
          CONNECTION.prepare('mimiku', 'INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at) values ($1, $2, $3)')
          CONNECTION.exec_prepared('mimiku',  [ { value: self.id}, { value: '2009-01-23 20:21:13' }, { value: '2009-01-23 20:21:13' }  ] )

        end
        # CONNECTION.close()
      end
    end
```

(added '2009-01-23 20:21:13' as Rails required created_at and updated_at for some reason).

I get this error:

```
ERROR: prepared statement "mimiku" already exists
```

Even if I change the name from 'mimiku' to 'somethingelse', I still get this type of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prepare` method returns a result according to the docs:
http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html#method-i-prepare

Maybe try call `exec_prepared` on the connection object

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection

def create_prizes

      begin 
        connection.describe_prepared('xixie')
      rescue PG::InvalidSqlStatementName
        connection.prepare('xixie', 'INSERT INTO prizes (deal_id) values ($1)')
      end

      Deal.transaction do  
        self.prize_number.times do |i| 
          connection.exec_prepared('xixie',  [ { value: self.id} ] )
        end
      end
end
```

UPDATE: I reworked the code above to first check if a prepared statement exists. If it doesn't exist it creates it. Sorry I haven't realized it in the first place but you don't need to prepare a statement more than once. This is the actual benefit of such a statement, since it has to be only parsed once and can than be executed with different values, which is then much faster than a regular query. 
As prepared statements last for the duration of the AR connection you only need to prepare it once.

Comment: will try tonight but I was already using exec_prepared, was I not?

Comment: yes but on the result object not on the connection. This eexplains the undefined method error.

Comment: Sorry for that. Only briefly looked into your answer and didn't realize how prepared statments were used. Updated the answer

Comment: have now a related question in order to delete fast those 300K created associated objects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553064/delete-faster-300k-associated-objects-on-activeadmin-rails-4-activeadmin