# Update massive number of rows of associated objects in has_many/belong_to relations (Rails 4, postgresql 9.4, activeadmin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activeadmin

When creating a model Deal, I use an after_create to create prizes on the DealPrize table.

Deal and DealPrize have a belong to/has_many relations: a Deal has many Deal prizes and a Dealprize belongs to a Deal.

It works like this: on my admin panel (using activeadmin), inside a Deal, I have a column 'prize-number' and I use an after_create so that every time the admin creates a new deal, the app takes this prize_number column, and create this volume of prizes (inserting as many rows as necessary=> often more than 300,000) inside the DealPrize table.

So I create a Deal, and automatically, the app creates a huge number of associated objects (prizes) say 300,000.

The problem is I might wish 2 days later to change the prize number from 300,000 to 272,000 for example (less prizes) or 324,000 (more prizes).

**How can I update the created Deal and tell my Rails app to update the number of associated Prizes (removing some or adding some) without deleeting and recreating the whole Deal object ?**

Also, I need a fast way (like the one I use to create the Deal => raw sql and transaction as the number of rows to create at once is very high).

**modals Deals.rb**

```
has_many   :deal_prizes,  dependent: :delete_all

after_create :create_deal_prizes

CONNECTION = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection

    def create_deal_prizes
      begin 
        CONNECTION.describe_prepared('yokoatxz')
      rescue PG::InvalidSqlStatementName
        CONNECTION.prepare('yokoatxz', 'INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id,created_at,updated_at,admin_user_id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)') 
      end

      Deal.transaction do  
        self.prizes_number.times do |i| 
          CONNECTION.exec_prepared('yokoatxz',  [ { value: self.id},
                                                  { value: '2009-01-23 20:21:13' },
                                                  { value: '2009-01-23 20:21:13' },
                                                  { value: self.admin_user_id }
                                                ] )
        end
      end
    end
```

Thanks for your help, Mathieu

Comment: What are you actually doing with these prices, apart from inserting and delting them?

Comment: well they're needed in some views. I need 200K seperate rows of approximately similar "prizes". Can't just have 1 row of prizes with a number= 200K. So each time i create a Deal, I tell Rails create 340,000 associated prizes. create and delete now are ok. Only problem is when I want to update the number of prizes (inside the prize_number column of Deal's table). For example, if I made a mistake on the number or even if there is a change in plans.

Comment: You're not displaying these prizes though, are you?

Comment: I create, update and delete them: they are created, updated or deleted ONLY when changing stuff inside Deal. It's like they're totally dependent on waht I do on the prize_number column inside Deal or if I delete a Deal then they must also be deleted.

Comment: i will use them in views yes but not all at once:)

Comment: So do you need to delete 60,000 at random, or place a condition on which are deleted?

Comment: some views will need to call the Dealprizes table to check if this dealprize id=34 is already taken or not and stuff, so yes views willm make calls to this DealsPrize table

Comment: Even if the prize has been taken?

Comment: sorry i am wrong, there will be a condition

Comment: exactly i will need to say something like: remove the 40K not needed among those where DealPrize's column called 'type' is equal 'foo' or where taken = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think that if you just wanted to change the number of deal_prizes then you could use a before_save callback on the Deal to test for a difference between prize_number and prize_number_was, and issue either an insert or delete statement appropriately.

I expect for the delete you'd do something like:

```
deal_prizes.limit(prize_number_was - prize_number).delete_all
```

... if you didn't care which were deleted.

You would probably want to use a scope on the deal_prizes:

```
def self.deletable
  where(:taken => false)
end
```

... to apply the condition by which rows can be deleted though, and then merge this into the association on deal ...

```
has_many :deletable_deal_prizes, -> {merge(DealPrize.deletable)}, :class_name => "DealPrize"
```

... so you can:

```
deleteable_deal_prizes.limit(prize_number_was - prize_number).delete_all
```

Comment: will try something like this. i'll have to provde for the case where i change from 300K to 330K (more prizes).

Comment: must go now but will try tomorrow, will validate the answer if it works. thansk again for your prcious help